# Express multiple production functions using 1 equation in GAMS

Tags: product, gams-math, economics

I have three production sectors, agriculture (AGR), industry (IND) and services (SRV) which use different inputs.
Agriculture is a function of capital (K), labour (L) and water (W). // AGR = (K(AGR)**alpha(AGR)) *(L(AGR)**beta(AGR)) * (W(AGR)**gamma(AGR))
Industry is a function of capital (K) and labour (L). //  IND= (K(IND)**alpha(IND)) *(L(IND)**beta(IND)))
Services are a function of capital and labour (L). // SRV = (K(SRV)**alpha(SRV)) *(L(SRV)**beta(SRV)) )

Do I need an equation to express each sector's production on GAMS? This is easy when it's just 3 production sectors, but what if there is more sectors? say 9 or 10? It's going to take a lot of effort.
I think there has to be a trick to use 1 equation in GAMS.

Can I express the production function in GAMS with 1 equation that includes water for agriculture and  excludes the use of water for Industry (IND) and services (SRV)?
Thank you. (I'm new to programming and GAMS)

(I'm new to programming and GAMS)

Comment: Hi! It would help if you could share more information about your model. What type of model is it? Is it a MILP? What are your decision variables? Are you multiplying all of your inputs or should they be added? 
I'm used to working with MILPs within operations and logistics, not sure I can help. But if you add more information someone else may be able to help :)